# What to do if I hate C++ header files?

Tags: c++, language-design, naming

I was always confused about header files. They are so strange: you include .h file which doesn't include .cpp but .cpp are somehow compiled too.

Recently I joined a team project, and of course, both .h and .cpp are used.
I understand that this is very important, but I can't live with copy-pasting every function declaration in each of multiple classes we have.

How do I handle the 2-file convention efficiently?
Are there any tools to help with that, or automatically change one file that looks like example below to .h and .cpp? (specifically for MS VC++ 2010)

```
class A
{
...
    Type f(Type a,Type b)
    {
        //implementation here, not in another file!
    }
...
};

Type f(Type a)
{
     //implementation here
}
...
```

Comment: It is assumed that your program will link against the standard (c or c++) library. You include the macros and prototypes to work with the parts of that library that you need using individual headers. Voting to close this as too localized, as it isn't really off topic, but doesn't quite belong on SO either.

Comment: This question could go a couple of ways .. "Why do we need headers when using c++" or, "Do you think a modern language that is meant to be compiled should be using headers?" As it is, it has 'What do I do" and "hate" in the title, which sets off a plethora of flags.

Comment: And yet, I can't pick a better one. Not a writer... "Why do we need headers..." isn't what I want to ask.

Comment: Your question makes it seem like you don't understand C++, or how whatever system you use compiles it. Learn to use it properly, and then ask more subjective questions.

Comment: The language is meant to be easy for the programmer, not for the compiler! I'd downvote this comment 10 times if I could.

Comment: @BlaXpirit:  C++, in particular, is to allow competent developers to do major things.  It has a lot of things developers need to learn.  It isn't newbie-friendly.  You can legitimately gripe about that, but if you are going to work in C++ you need to learn the language as it is.  The first two sentences in your original question make it clear you aren't comfortable with it.

Comment: Can I not like one thing in C++ without you implying that I'm a newbie?

Comment: Your first sentence indicates that you don't "understand everything about headers".  Including a .h file does not cause the corresponding .cpp file to be "somehow compiled too".  You compile .cpp files independently in their own right. If you haven't compiled the corresponding .cpp, then the inclusion of a header without a corresponding object file will cause the linker to fail.

Comment: @BlaXpirit:  Read your first paragraph.  You use phrases like "so strange" and "are somehow" to describe something most of us just accept as a minor oddity and annoyance, since we do know what's going on.  Not liking something about C++ doesn't mark you as a newbie (if you liked all of it you knew I'd suspect you were a newbie), but describing it as if it were weird and wonderful does.

Comment: "The language is meant to be easy for the programmer, not for the compiler".  That's pretty much false.  Look at Java, which does away with the separate `.h` file.  It's an optimization.  Programmers do more work and the compiler does less work, making it super fast.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Nope, C++ was never meant to be an easy language. It's a language that gives you acces to the lower levels close to the machine. It's a language where the programmer works more, so that the computer can work less. Some languages, like Basic and Logo, were designed to be easy. C and C++ were not.

Comment: @BlaXpirit - It appears you may have touched a nerve for some people. ;) Personally, I like to stay DRY, so I hate the duplication, too.

Comment: What to do? Find another language if it bugs you that much.

Comment: About the "can't live with copy-pasting": Whenever one updates a function, one has to update all places where it is called anyway. As the callers are much harder to find than the declaration in the header file, updating the header is just a minor detail.

Comment: @BlaXpirit - When you ask a silly question, a question that makes you sound like you never touched C++ in your entire life, then you will appear to be a "newbie"

Comment: I get that header files/imports/includes can be annoying sometimes, especially when you're first learning a language, but they're there for a reason. Most programmers really appreciate having them around. It might be worth trying to learn more about why others who know more about them appreciate them so much before rejecting them outright. *What do they see in header files that you don't?* (This is a principle that applies broadly in life, too.)

Comment: Wait for the module features of C++20

Comment: Have you considered to use a different programming language? Most OOP languages which were developed after C++ have noticed that header files are redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Lzz](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/). It's a command line tool that takes declarations written in a C++ syntax and generates the header and source files.

Comment: Substituting auto-generation for a lack of programmer skill and knowledge is a bad solution.

Comment: Also you may not want to to expose in the header the whole stuff you wrote in your cpp.

Answer (score 23):

#### Writing More Refactoring Friendly C++

In C++ you don't *have* to use headers at all.  You can define the whole object in one file just as you would with C# or Java.  C developers will commonly only keep external calls in a header file.  All the internal calls would be defined in the .c file.  By the same token, you can reserve your C++ .h files for the classes/interfaces (pure virtual abstract classes)/etc. that are intended to be shared outside the DLL.  For internal classes/structs/interfaces, etc. you would simply include the .cpp file you need:

```
#include<myclass.cpp>
```

This doesn't seem to be the most popular approach, but it is legal C++.  It would definitely be a possibility for all your internal code.  This allows the internal code and set of classes to change a lot more radically while providing a more stable interface for code outside your library/executable to interact with.

Having your whole class inside one file will make it easier to do what you want.  It won't solve the problem of renaming a method and having to search down every place that method is called, but it will make sure you have more intelligable error messages.  Nothing worse than having your header declare a method one way, but you implement it differently.  Other code that calls the header file will compile properly and you'll get a link exception, while the implementation file will be the one that complains that the method wasn't defined.  When you define every method in place (in the actual class declaration), you'll get the same error message no matter what file includes it.

You may also want to look at this question: [Good refactoring tools for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167/good-refactoring-support-for-c)

#### How C/C++ Resolves Header/Implementation Files

At the base C level (and C++ is built on that foundation), the header files declare the *promise* of a function/struct/variable which is enough to allow a compiler to create the object file.  Similarly C++ header files declare the promise of functions, structs, classes, etc.  It is this definition that the compiler uses to reserve space in the stack, etc.

The the .c or .cpp files have the implementation.  As the compiler converts each implementation file to an object file, there are hooks to unimplemented concepts (what was declared in the header).  The linker ties the hooks to the implementations in other object files and creates a larger binary that includes all the code (shared library or executable).

#### VS Specific

As to working with those in Visual Studio, there are some wizards that help make things a bit easier.  The new class wizard will create your matching pair of header and implementation files.  There is even a class browser feature that will allow you declare new methods.  It will inject the definition in the header and the implementation stub in the .cpp file.  Visual Studio has had those features for more than a decade (as long as I've used them).

Comment: The problem is, I'm heavily modifying the classes all the time, not just adding new functions, etc

Comment: @BlaXpirit:  So, why are you heavily modifying the classes all the time?  One of the ideas behind OO design is to have a lot of fairly stable building blocks.  If I were heavily modifying classes, I'd like a more dynamic language, like Common Lisp or Python.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'm improving/modifying the "building blocks" and adding new ones

Comment: C++ has never been refactoring friendly.  The concept of refactoring didn't gain momentum until there were tools that made it really easy to do in Java IDEs.  NOTE: those features were there for Smalltalk developers, and other languages, but it didn't become mainstream until it was available for a lot of people.  So far I have yet to see someone intelligently implement that for C++.  Perhaps Resharper from JetBrains?  I know it does C# and VB code, but I'm not sure if it will give you C++ refactoring.

Comment: @Berin:  I went looking for C++ refactoring tools a year or two ago, and found two things.  They were fairly pricey at the time, and I didn't see trial versions, so I don't know what they did.  Moreover, one worked with emacs only, which would limit its effectiveness in a Visual Studio shop.

Comment: @David Thornley.  I know it is _technically_ possible, but due to the the complexity of the language and the seeming lack of demand, the prices will be much higher.  I've noticed almost all C++ specific tools are much pricier.  Perhaps it's just an expectation for that language...

Answer (score 21):

Become a Java developer.

If you really must carry on developing in C++, you could try using an IDE.  Often they offer some mechanism by which you can add a method to a class, and it automagically places the declaration in the .h file and the definition in the .cpp file.

Comment: kthx, I somewhat know Java, but you can't make low-level Win32 DLLs with it, can you?

Comment: I don't know why, but 'Become a Java developer' somehow sounds like an insult :D.

Comment: @BlaXpirit, Not natively, no.  There is a Java/C bridge where you can wrap your Win32 DLLs with Java objects.  @Helper Method, Having been a Java Developer, I know what you mean.  :)

Comment: If you want to do low level, forget everything about 'easy languages'. Low level costs sweat and tears.

Comment: Not a particularly helpful answer.

Comment: @Batibix Ada is a couple orders of magnitude simpler than C/C++ (it eliminates entire classes of errors). It's probably actually a little more sane than VM languages in a lot of ways as well.

Comment: @OliverWeiler I don't perceive "become a Java developer" as an insult.  I program both in C++ and Java, but my preference by far is Java because it's so much easier to sit down and bang out code that works (and more portable).  If you for some reason detest the existence of header files, trying Java may be the right choice (though it's odd you would hate header files; I'd consider a change in IDE).

Comment: @Batibix C++ is not low-level, and Java isn't much "higher-level" than C++.  If you are referring to things like flexibility of selecting stack vs. heap, optimizers kind of quashed that difference a long time ago.

Comment: Certainly a simple answer to the question "What to do if I hate C++ header files?"

Comment: @ChrisF: When a poster "hates" and doesn't understand a fundamental language feature, what is a helpful answer if not recommending a different language that doesn't have that feature?

Comment: This is not the answer to any question.

Answer (score 10):

You could be interested in the [makeheaders](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/) program from Hwaci (those who do SQLite and Fossil).

Also have a look at [how fossil is built](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/makefile.wiki) to have an idea.

Comment: The asker still needs to understand the relationship between .h and .cpp quite well.

Comment: I understand the basics. The answer seems to be just what I need.

Comment: @OlehPrypin: If you think "you include .h file which doesn't include .cpp but .cpp are somehow compiled too" then you don't understand the very basics of this.

Answer (score 6):

When you write the first lines of a new class, it usually is because you need it in one place only at that time. At a later time, it might be used at more places, but initially it usually isn't.

Many of my classes start at the top of the current .cpp file. When it has stablized enough to use it in multiple places, I cut-paste it to a header. Though often the class disappears as fast as it appeared.

Answer (score 5):

The Header (.h) file describes the *interface* to the code, because that's the *only* bit that *other* code gets to see.

The Source (.cpp) file provides the implementation of the code that nobody else needs to know about.

> you include .h file which doesn't include .cpp ...

Correct.

As a consumer of this code, you only need the Header file so that the compiler knows what's available in that code for you to work with.  The C++ source code is not used in any way, shape or form at this point (or, at least, it *shouldn't* be).

> ... but .cpp are somehow compiled too.

Yes that are, but completely *separately*.

The .cpp file of a module/library that you are using is compiled into an Object file (.o / .dll) by the Developer of that library.   That object file will contain entry points that are the same "shape" as those described in the Header file.

You will need that Object file when you come to *link* your finished executable, at which point the Linker may grab the contents of the Object file and embed it into your executable (that's for static linking; dynamic linking gets more complicated)
Basically the linker has to "joins the dots" between the entry points that your code *expects* to be able to call, based on what it saw in the Header file, and what's actually in the library itself.

Answer (score -2):

As a suggestion to help handle C++ header files, is common to use them without file extension or file suffix, such as "GCC" libraries does.

If this is your case, I suggest to use a "*.hpp" (or unleast "*.hxx") file extension or file suffix.

You may have to configure your compiler, developer enviroment, or Built program.

Comment: Are you talking about how when you include a file like `#include <iostream>`? Those aren't just for the GCC library. In fact, its defined in the [1997 C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/), section 17.3.1.2. I would avoid naming files like that. You can, but the reason the C++ standard library did that was probably to avoid naming conflicts. I actually find it really weird when compilers automatically add a '.h' when you include a header, it seems pretty unstandard to me. And I don't ever see anyone name headers without suffix except for the c++ standard library.

Comment: Also, I should note, all of the compilers that I have used, except for borland (which I hate so very much), don't automatically add a '.h' or '.hpp' or '.hxx' when you try to include a file with no suffix. Don't expect `#include <someclass>` to be read as `#include <someclass.hpp>` on all compilers. Your code will break.

Answer (score -4):

Become a Swift developer. No header files. Except if you say to yourself “I wish I could see only the things that a user of this file needs”, you tell the IDE to show the interface of the file, with all implementations and with all non-public functions gone. (One better than C++ header files containing inline definitions and private methods).